# How do I ask apt-get to skip any interactive post-install configuration steps?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have a server build script which uses apt-get to install packages. It then puts pre-written configuration files directly in place, so the interactive post-install configuration dialog in packages such as postfix is not needed. How do I skip this stage of the installation? It creates a piece of manual intervention that I would rather avoid.

I am aware of the `-qq` option, but the manpage warns against using it without specifying a no-action modifier. I *do* want to perform an action, I just want to suppress a specific part of it.

Answer (score 312, accepted):

You can do a couple of things for avoiding this. Setting the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` variable to `noninteractive` and using `-y` flag. For example:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -yq install [packagename]
```

If you need to install it via sudo, use:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq install [packagename]
```

Comment: This worked for me until one day it didn't. Some kind of "urgency=high" message. You need `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`, `y` AND the `q` flag set, i.e. `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -yq install [packagename]`

Comment: Did no work for me when installing iptables-persistent :/

Answer (score 2):

I've found that setting `-yqq` and `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` don't work in some cases where `apt-get` stalls at the end with

```
Restarting the system to load the new kernel will not be handled automatically, so you should consider
rebooting. [Return]
```

It will not exit until after you press the `enter` key.

My solution to this is to do everything everyone else suggested, but also with `yes` piped to `apt-get` as follows

```
yes | sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yqq purge 'my-package'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine `apt` as a function in your bash scripts if you are going to be running these commands regularly in automated stacks, so that you don't have to remember everything:

```
## apt ##
function apt {
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    export DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical
    export PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
    command /usr/bin/apt --yes --quiet --option Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold --option Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef "$@"
}
```

Or better yet just rename it to like `my_apt` or whatever.

And then it can be used in child functions, here are some examples we use in [SlickStack](https://github.com/littlebizzy/slickstack/blob/master/bash/ss-functions.txt):

```
## ss_apt_update ##
function ss_apt_update {
    apt update > /dev/null 2>&1
}

## ss_apt_upgrade ##
function ss_apt_upgrade {
    apt upgrade > /dev/null 2>&1
}

## ss_apt_full_upgrade ##
function ss_apt_full_upgrade {
    apt full-upgrade > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```