# How do I ask apt-get to skip all post-install configuration steps?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

When installing some packages (like RabbitMQ) on Debian/Ubuntu machines, the `post-install` step defaults to starting the service.

While this is great in most cases, in some cases (when you already have a service running on the needed port for example) this fails which makes `apt-get` fail completely.

Is there a way to tell `apt-get` to skip all those `post-install` steps so it can still install properly?

**Note** This is not about questions during install, even in interactive sessions these installs fail because the `post-install` step fails failure is not handled correctly

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=policy-rc.d

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I ask apt-get to skip any interactive post-install configuration steps?](https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps)

Comment: That question is similar but different. This is about skipping all steps, not just the interactive ones. Some tasks automatically execute scripts which are not always wanted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[How do I ask apt-get to skip any interactive post-install configuration steps?](https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-post-install-configuration-steps)

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get install -y [packagename]
```

**Edit**: yes, that was for skipping (well, automating) post-install *questions*, true - sorry.

There is no way to skip post-install *scripts*.  The official Debian policy is to edit the script to return a non-terminal error, or fix the script.  See http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/251

It sounds like you're automating this for many servers, in which case, you'll probably want to make your own version of the package and deploy that.  Another option is to email the package maintainer and discuss whether a failure-to-start should be a terminal error for post-install (I don't believe it is for other packages like apache or lighttpd, for example, but I could be wrong.)

Comment: That's just to skip interactive steps. Those are not the problem here, these are the non-interactive `post-install` steps that fail if something like `service rabbitmq-server start` fails.

Comment: Updated. Does that help?

Comment: it does, better to know that it's not possible than wondering if it is :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're using sudo the export of the environment variable won't work, but you can do it this way: `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y [packagename]`

Answer (score 5):

What you may want to do is something with the **policy-rc.d**.  See the man page for invoke-rc.d.  You can set a policy so services will not be automatically started.

Comment: That's a way to work around it, but that would be a temporary measure I assume? Atleast... I think that way you would globally disable all service starts.

Answer (score 3):

this should work

```
echo exit 101 > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
apt-get install <packagename>
rm -f /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
```

Comment: A bit hacky and very specific to this case, but it does help a lot! Thanks :)