# Installing and configuring phpmyadmin completely through a shell script

Tags: linux, shell-scripting

Referencing this tutorial: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04/ for installing PHP-Admin, after installing the package, on "Step 2: Basic Configuration" some questions need to be filled out by the user.

Is it possible to complete these configurations entirely via Shell Script from the command line?

Comment: I would assume so but just a guess. I wonder if that screen pops up automatically after the install or do you have to run something first?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have created a shell script for that and when I execute this command : apt install apache2 mysql-server php libapache2-mod-php phpmyadmin python python-mysqldb the referred screens show up. I would like to answer these questions via shell script avoiding user input but maybe is not possible.

Comment: I know you want a shell script. I asked about the screen thing to see if it popped up on its own or if you had to trigger it. Looks like Esa gives a fix for turning off this.

Comment: Debian packages tend to be interactive and there are a variety of imperfect methods for working around that.  I'd rather work on an `rpm`-based system that can be scripted without worrying about interactive BS.

Answer (score 6):

Basically the first thing to do is [skipping any interactive post-install configuration steps](https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps).

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -yq install phpmyadmin
```

This will skip all the questions made by [`dpkg-preconfigure`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/dpkg-preconfigure.8.html).

Then, you need to do configuration *manually* i.e. automate it by yourself by making your script to either create or copy configuration. The local configuration file is in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` and you can find some configuration examples in `/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/`. For security, passwords should be included from a separate file with permissions `-rw-r----- root www-data`.

The `dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin` reads and writes from `/etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf`. Your script could be something like this:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -yq install phpmyadmin
cp /path/to/preconfigured-phpmyadmin.conf /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf
dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this script helps. I am still working out how to automate apache configuration

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -yq phpmyadmin

# Set the MySQL administrative user's password
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install boolean true"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-user string root"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass password $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass password $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver multiselect apache2"

sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive phpmyadmin

echo "Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

sudo service apache2 restart
echo "Apache service restarted"
```