# How to fix "Setting up grub-pc" freezing during apt-get upgrade?

Tags: apt, grub2

I have a packer script that builds up a virtual image using Ubuntu. The script today started getting stuck during `apt-get dist-upgrade` on `amazon-ebs: Setting up grub-pc`.

I found many people on the net complaining about similar situations with various ad-hoc proposals but no clear fixing instructions. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in my case, the problem was that the post-installation opened an interactive prompt notifying that a configuration file had been locally changed (though we don't modify it ourselves) and asking whether I want to keep the config file or use the provided new one.

I discovered this by looking at the apt-get log file: `cat /var/log/apt/term.log`

The solution is to force non-interactive update using *both* `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` environment variable and `-yq` option ([source](https://serverfault.com/a/227194/212955)):

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -yq dist-upgrade
```

To my understanding this will install the new configuration version, but not 100% sure. Further insight on this would be appreciated.