# How to check if APT package *needs* interaction on upgrade before running the upgrade itself?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

Some APT packages upgrade without asking any questions, e.g. if no configuration files are changed. Others don't.

I would like to *check* if a package *needs* or *"wants"* interaction on upgrade.

I do **not** mean forced, non-interactive installs/upgrades like https://serverfault.com/a/227194/174041. I would simply like to automate "safe" upgrades (I have unattended security upgrades anyway, but would like to also automatically upgrade packages that can be relatively safely upgraded in automated manner).

Comment: @anx: Back out and warn / produce error, abort the whole effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```sh
apt-cache show postifx
```

you will see it depends on debconf which is commonly used to ask questions during package setup.
And this shows:

```sh
apt-cache show debconf
...
Description-en: ...Packages use Debconf to ask questions when they are installed.
...
```