# How can I suppress the Old Runlevel warning while installing Strongswan

Tags: installation, ipsec, strongswan, debian-stretch, runlevel

When I install `strongswan` and dependent packages using `apt install`, I get the following warning prompt:

[image]

This inhibits me from installing strongswan through an automated unattended install script.

Therefore, how can I suppress this prompt.

I am using **Debian 9 Stretch (Version: 4.9.189-3+deb9u2)** with **kernel: 4.9.0-11-amd64**. The APT version is **v1.4.9** and strongswan I am installing is version **5.5.1-4+deb9u4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable to `noninteractive` and pass the `-y` (yes) and `-q` (quiet) flags to `apt`

```sh
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo apt install -yq {PACKAGE}
```

Credit:
[How do I ask apt-get to skip any interactive post-install configuration steps?](https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps)