# Deb installation asks me to give inputs

Tags: ubuntu, mta-sts

When I trying to install 'nullmailer' in Ubuntu Jammy(22.04), it prompts to provide some required inputs like **Mailname of your system:**. Is there any way to avoid prompts while installing and configuring it post install ?

```
:/opt# dpkg -i ./nullmailer_2.2-3build1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package nullmailer.
(Reading database ... 67792 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nullmailer_2.2-3build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nullmailer (1:2.2-3build1) ...
Setting up nullmailer (1:2.2-3build1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 78.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Configuring nullmailer
----------------------

This is the fully-qualified host name of the computer running nullmailer. It defaults to the literal name 'me'.

Mailname of your system:

This is a colon-separated list of remote servers to which to send each message. Each entry contains a remote host name or address followed by an optional protocol string 'host protocol'.
The protocol name defaults to smtp, and may be followed by command-line arguments for that module.
```

Thanks.

Comment: The manual page for `debconf` is named [debconf](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man7/debconf.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in lot of threads, you can [avoid questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps) doing this :

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq install [packagename]
```

Then, you will need to configure the package. You can also use Ansible and these modules to automate the task and apply your configuration and install it in a non-interactive way.