# Unable to force Debian to do unattended install... libc6 wants interactive confirm

Tags: debian, apt, automated-install, dpkg, libc6

I'm trying to create a script that forces a Debian Lenny install to install the latest version of CRAN R. During the install it appears libc6 is upgraded and the install wants interactive confirm that it's OK to restart three services (mysql, exim4, cron). This process HAS to be unattended as it runs on Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce (EMR) machines. But I'm running out of options. Here's a few things I've tried:

This [previous question](https://serverfault.com/q/48724/14618) appears to be exactly what I'm looking for. So I set up my install script as follows:

```
# set my CRAN repos... yes, I know there's a new convention where to put these. 
echo "deb http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian lenny-cran/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian lenny-cran/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

# set the dpkg.cfg options per the previous SuperUser question
echo "force-confold" | sudo tee -a  /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg
echo "force-confdef" | sudo tee -a  /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# add key to keyring so it doesn't complain 
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-key 381BA480
gpg -a --export 381BA480 > jranke_cran.asc
sudo apt-key add jranke_cran.asc

sudo apt-get update

# install the latest R
sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes r-base
```

But this script hangs with the following request for input:

[image]

OK, so I tried stopping the services using the following script:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/exim4 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/cron stop
sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes libc6
```

This does not work and the interactive screen comes back, but this time with only cron listed as the service that must be restarted.

So is there a way to make libc6 just restart these services with no user input? Or is there a way to stop cron so it does not cause an interactive prompt? Maybe a creative option I've never thought of?

Keep in mind that this system is brought up, some Hadoop code is run, and then it's torn down. So I can put up with side effects and bad behavior that we might not want in a production desktop machine or web server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu dpkg, non interactive installation](http://serverfault.com/questions/197495/ubuntu-dpkg-non-interactive-installation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not positive on the settings in Lenny but I know that in Squeeze, sudo is configured with `env_reset` meaning it will strip out all but a very few select env variables before running the command.

This means the **DEBIAN_FRONTEND** variable you set is never actually making it to the `apt-get install --yes --force-yes r-base`. If you have full access to sudo, meaning you are in the sudoers files with `ALL = ALL` permissions, then you can override this behavior.

Try using the following instead.

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --yes --force-yes r-base
```

Edit: Note that rewriting the script to not use sudo everywhere and instead run the script as root would also work. But doing that would just be avoiding the real problem I pointed out instead of solving it and learning from it.

Comment: I voted up, but also recommend changing the command to `sudo sh -c "DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --yes --force-yes r-base"`

Comment: @bahamat, I tested both @arrowmaster's solution as yours. Both work for me. Thank you both very much. What's the advantage of passing the command to `sh -c`?

Comment: @JD Long: The `sh -c` method is assured to work as long as you are allowed to run sh through sudo. The one I used can be rejected by sudo depending on the sudo config, but I find it highly unlikely that would happen in a situation that you could use `sh -c` as an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

### Step 1

On the host that had the package installed manually (interactive option selection) run:

```
apt-get install debconf-utils
debconf-get-selections > answers.conf
```

### Step 2 (Optional)

At this point you may want to filter **answers.conf** to include the configuration answers only for specific package(s). I tested without filtering.

### Step 3

When creating a new host, include **answers.conf** along with your automatic installation script. Before running `apt-get install`, in the script, run:

```
debconf-set-selections --verbose < answers.conf
```

### Result

This will fill the debconf database with predefined answers. The interactive questions will not be asked when you run `apt-get install`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I've got an ugly, but working solution. But I'm keepign the `debconf` options you point out in the back of my mind. I may need those next time.

Answer (score 4):

A more concise variant of the debconf solution mentioned in another answer is the following:

> echo 'libc6 libraries/restart-without-asking boolean true' | sudo debconf-set-selections

I just used this solution successfully when upgrading glibc on Debian 7 (wheezy).

For the curious, the way I found the right configuration variable to set was as follows:

> sudo apt-get install debconf-utils
>
> sudo apt-get install -y libc6   # answer prompt interactively
>
> debconf-get-selections | grep libc6

Comment: It is nice that you provided the tools you used to get the answer.  That could help the next guy find the answer to a different problem.

Answer (score 2):

Besides what we discussed in email, there is also the saying

> If you can't beat'em, join'em.

so you could create a virtual machine on your laptop which corresponds to the (base) packages on the cloud instance, and then rebuild your own local R 2.12.1 .deb against those packages.  As no upgraded `libc6` is involved, you'd sidestep the issue.

Or, in line with your comment on possible side-effects being permitted, you could uninstall exim4, mysql and cron.  Your R jobs won't need them.  Something like

```
sudo dpkg --force-depends --remove ...names of your packages here...
```

but I can't really believe I recommend this :)   You may need a trial and error to get all related exim and mysql packages.

Comment: Now we're talking brute force! ;) I tried uninstalling cron and it makes me type a confirm phrase, something like, "I know I am insane, but it's OK"

Comment: Ah, damn, yes. I think packages of a certain Priority: may get that.  So back to building a custom / local R .deb package?  Or can't you just bloody run R from lenny (and fetch the corresponding CRAN packages 'manually' from the Archive section on CRAN?

Comment: This was a way bigger pain in my ass than I ever imagined it would be. The kludge below has bought me some time... for now. Thanks again for helping me brainstorm ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to deduce that the libc6 installer was prompting to restart cron **even if cron was not running** which seems odd. At any rate I was able to get around that by renaming the cron init.d scripts so that the package installer was fooled into not thinking cron was present. Ugh. What a mess:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/exim4 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/cron stop
sudo mv /etc/init.d/cron /etc/init.d/cron.bak
sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes libc6
sudo mv /etc/init.d/cron.bak /etc/init.d/cron
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
sudo /etc/init.d/exim4 start
sudo /etc/init.d/cron start
```

After that little kabuki dance I can install the latest R.

Comment: Yay. Good enough for government, err, modeling work as we say.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
printf "\n" | sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes libc6
```

Comment: I suggested that earlier to JD; it is what leads to the `libc6` upgrade creating the trouble he is having.

Comment: the `pringf "\n" | ` bit is novel. I like it, but I tried it and, for some reason it did not cause the confirm page to go away. God only knows what ate the `\n`.

Comment: Try putting multiple \n's

Comment: oddly enough it does something weird at the blue screen. If I add the `printf "\n"` then the cursor is no longer in the box and I can't navigate the screen at all. Really odd. I was hopeful for this hack.